# query dsl order by collection size with param

Tags: java, sql-order-by, querydsl

Is it possible in QueryDSL to order by collections size with additional params?

For example, when I just order by collection size `OrderSpecifier<Integer> severity = alarmSet.alarms.size().desc();` it produces next SQL:

```
ORDER BY (SELECT 
        COUNT(alarms.AL_ALARM_SET_ID)
    FROM
        ALARM alarms
    WHERE
        alarmset.ID = alarms.AL_ALARM_SET_ID) DESC
```

But I want it to add condition to WHERE `AND alarms.AL_STATUS = 1` and produce next:

```
    ORDER BY (SELECT 
            COUNT(alarms.AL_ALARM_SET_ID)
        FROM
            ALARM alarms
        WHERE
            alarmsets.ID = alarms.AL_ALARM_SET_ID 
            AND alarms.AL_STATUS = 1) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's impossible to do this kind of job in QueryDsl(if **possible** please provide solution!).
But I found other way- add custom column with count of alarms and order by this column.

```
//crete subquery to count the size of child collection
Expression<Long> countExpression = ExpressionUtils.as(JPAExpressions
                    .select(ExpressionUtils.count(alarm))
                    .from(alarmSet.alarms, alarm)
                    .where(alarm.alStatus.eq(1)), "customCount");
```

After that order by custom column:

```
OrderSpecifier<Long> severity = new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.DESC, Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "customCount"));
```

And using Tuple to select data:

```
query.select(Projections.tuple(room, countExpression)).fetch();
```